# Django annotate fails when querying unique values

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

for a Django project I need to combine two parts lists into one.

**models.py**:

```
class UserBuild(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    part = models.ForeignKey(Parts)
    part_quantity = models.IntegerField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    suggested_quantity = models.IntegerField(
        max_length=5, null=True, blank=True
    )
```

**views.py**:

```
def CombineProjects(request, template_name='combined_projects.html'):
    ...
    build_set = UserBuild.objects.values(
        #'pk',
        #'project__pk',
        'part__number',
        'part__part_type__name',
        'part__price',
        'part__description',
        'part__category__name'
    ).filter(
        project__in=projects
    ).order_by('part__category', 'part__part_type').annotate(total=Sum('part_quantity'))
```

Basically here I want to group all parts which are the same and sum their quantity. As above works but if I uncomment either the `pk` or `project__pk` arguments, then the parts are no longer grouped (I assume because they are variable even when the part is the same).

Is there some way that I can keep the grouping but also include the `pk` and `project__pk` values?

Comment: Grouping on pk does not make sense ... it's unique in this context so there is nothing to sum or group by.   What are you actually trying to count?

Comment: I want to sum the quantities of parts with the same number, but I also need the other values to be available. I don't actually need the `pk` but I do need the `project__pk`. Everything works exactly as I want until I uncomment `project__pk`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your list of values is what you group and sum by; so you really want to group by project and part number only.

I would try:

```
build_set = UserBuild.objects.values(
    'project__pk',
    'part__number',
).filter(
    project__in=projects
).order_by('part__category', 'part__part_type').annotate(total=Sum('part_quantity'))
```

then merge the other attributes into this list later on.   I'm not sure this will work however.   You might need to do:

```
build_set = UserBuild.objects.values(
    'project_id',
    'part_id',
).filter(
    project__in=projects
).order_by('part__category', 'part__part_type').annotate(total=Sum('part_quantity'))
```

And do more work by hand afterwards.

Comment: Actually, I ended up doing the first query without the `pk` values. I was able to use the `projects` listlater to get my project instances. Definitely taught me a little as how `annotate` works.